# How to turn off internet on RasPi without disconnecting it from the local network

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, gateway

Is there way I can turn off only the internet off the RasPi.

I have set up several things that starts downloading files, torrents, videos on my RasPi as soon as it starts. This really slows down the internet of the home network. To get better I have to turn the power off of the RasPi. But it takes effort to go turn the power off the RasPi. I have thinking if there is any way I can stop RasPi from using the internet, not disconnecting it from the network cause that would be a big trouble. Just stopping the internet access of RasPi so no external IPs can be reached. I was thinking if this can be done through browser of any device within the local network, so that I can turn ON/OFF the internet of the RasPi. Please let me know if anything like that exist, or you can create something like this.

Thanks

Comment: `ifconfig eth0 down`? remove the default gateway/route?

Comment: How can I restore it back on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two commands worked fine for me

To stop the internet:`ip route del default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0`

To turn it back on:`ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0`